# Angular routing with parameters in a child, lazy-loaded module? Can't match any routes thrown every time

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7, angular-module

I have a lazy loaded module which defaults to `SuperUserComponent` inside this component I have toggle navigation with ngSwitchCase between 4-5 child components. Because I'm using this with nativescript I need to have a separate routing module for this whole routing module.

Inside my main routing module I have:

```
 {
    path: 'super-user',
    loadChildren: './super-user/super-user.module#SuperUserModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Inside the module's own child routing module I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':resource',
    component: SuperUserComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

The toggles for the switchase is as follows:

```
   <mat-button-toggle
        [routerLink]="['/super-user', 'manage-users']"
        value="manage-users"
      >
        Users
      </mat-button-toggle>
```

And on the backend I listen for that parameter every time I load the main component:

```
this.paramSubscription = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const newValue = params.get('resource');
      this.superUserMenu = newValue;
    });
```

How can I configure that child routing module to match that parameter when loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some research, all you need is to change your mai nrouting module

```
 {
    path: 'super-user',
    loadChildren: './super-user/super-user.module#SuperUserModule',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
 }
```

or just remove that line `pathMatch: 'prefix'` if you don't need that. I think you just forcing angular to find route that ends with 'super-user', but he, obiously, can't do that.

Comment: Ah, I honestly don't know exactly how that pathMatch parameter even works, it's just that every single time I had an issue with routing all the threads/tutorials I could ifnd would suggest to make that 'full' so after I while I stopped questioning it. I ended up making it something like `./super-user/:resource/super-user.module#...` and then from my menu the button takes you directly to one of the sub-resources with a default. I will give your option a shot as well though!